# Creating a Node for a Linked List where the Data Lacks a Default Constructor

Tags: c++, linked-list, initialization, c++14, default-constructor

I am trying to implement a class that represents a doubly-linked list, and I have a function `createNode()` which returns a new `Node` (A templated class) with all its members initialized. This function is going to be used to create linked lists where the size is known, but no data has been passed to it. For most data types, this works. However, this does *not* work for classes without default constructors, since they cannot be initialized without parameters. Here is the minimal code that exhibits this:

```
class Test // A class without a default constructor
{
public:
    Test(int value) : value_{ value } { };
private:
    int value_;
};

template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    T value;
};

template<typename T>
Node<T>* createNode()
{
    return new Node<T>{ nullptr, nullptr, T() }; // How do I change T() so
                                                 // that I can use classes
                                                 // without default constructors?
}

int main()
{
    Node<Test>* testNode = createNode<Test>();
    delete testNode;
}
```

Basically, my final goal is to be able to create a linked list which can hold uninitialized nodes while keeping track of which nodes are initialized or not. I remember reading in an old textbook of mine about a method for solving this problem that involves using allocators (Which are used for handling construction/destruction of objects), but I don't remember the exact technique at all. So how should I go about this?

Comment: Not related to your particular problem, but why are you rolling your own list class if there's `std::list` already? Any solicit reason to do so?

Comment: For learning how to implement one? This Linked List obviously won't serve any practical use, but knowing how one works is valuable information.

Comment: I think you just allocate enough memory and use placement new

Comment: Could you elaborate (Maybe with an example)?

Comment: Allocate memory for one object `buf = new char[sizeof(T)];` and later construct it in this memory `T* pT = new (buf) T(...);`. You need to call the destructor yourself later. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: Why don't you just store a pointer `T *valueptr` instead? What is the point of having a linked list containing only copies of your elements?

Comment: The buffer cold be just a member var char buf[sizeof(T)]  the above example is more dor an allocator allocating memory for more then one object

Comment: @realUser404 Because that is what the standard library's list does.

Comment: @A.A Again, still need more clarification. What 'buffer' are you referring to? What 'object's are you referring to? If I wanted to create a linked list, why would I use an array?

Comment: It's just abbout splitting the memory allocation ftom the construction of the objects. So you can declare a member in your node that takes memory but do not construct object because it needs parameter. Later you can construct the object wit the needed parameters but not allocate memory with new but use placement new to just call the constructor with memory already allocated with the node

Comment: @A.A Ah, yes, that is _exactly_ what I am looking for. Is there a way to achieve something similar with `std::allocator` (Or any standard library utility that allows me to make this less ugly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) to place the object later in a pre-allocated memory.

It's just about splitting the memory allocation from the construction of the objects. So you can declare a member in your `Node` that takes memory but do not construct object because it needs parameter. Later you can construct the object with the needed parameters but not allocate memory with `new` but use placement new to just call the constructor with memory already allocated within the `Node`.

So following is an example of a self-made [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). In [n3527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html) you can find more details about `std::optional`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Test // A class without a default constructor
{
public:
    Test(int value) : value_{ value } { };
//private:
    int value_;
};

template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;

    bool empty = true;
    union {
        T t;
    } value;    // Could be replaced with typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type value;

    // need a constructor that inits the value union and activate a field
    // Node()

    ~Node() {
        if (!empty) {
            value.t.~T();
        }
    }
    template<typename... Args>
    void setValue(Args... args) {
        if (!empty) {
            value.t.~T();
        }
        new (&value.t) T(std::forward<Args...>(args...));
        empty = false;
    }

    T& getValue() {
        // TODO:
        if (empty) {
            //throw
        }
        return value.t;
    }
};

template<typename T>
Node<T>* createNode()
{
    return new Node<T>{ nullptr, nullptr }; // How do I change T() so
                                                 // that I can use classes
                                                 // without default constructors?
}

int main()
{
    Node<Test>* testNode = createNode<Test>();
    testNode->setValue(42);
    if (!testNode->empty) {
        std::cout << testNode->getValue().value_;
    }
    delete testNode;
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3b15263f4450efa)</kbd>

With few small changes and with `reinterpret_cas`s you can also use `typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type value;` - <kbd>[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b39125dddb6aa5de)</kbd>

[Allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) manage the memory and you will not be able include (aggregate) the object in your class and have to use pointers and second allocation except you use allocator to place the entire `Node`.

There are interesting presentation form John Lakos about allocators on YouTube - [CppCon 2017 Local 'Arena' Memory Allocators part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLBkLn0h2f4) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMTetdSk800).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: But this example is more for learning how could it be done, but i would use std::optional.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::optional<T>` if you have access to C++17, or `boost::optional<T>` if you don't.

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    std::optional<T> value;  // or boost::optional<T> value;
};

template<typename T>
Node<T>* createNode()
{
    return new Node<T>{ nullptr, nullptr, std::nullopt /* or boost::none */ };
}
```

If you don't have access to C++17 and don't want to include boost, you could roll your own `optional` template with something like this:

```
struct nullopt_t {};
nullopt_t nullopt;

template <typename T>
class optional
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    optional(Args&&... args)
        : ptr{new ((void*)&storage) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)}
    {}

    optional(nullopt_t)
        : ptr{nullptr}
    {}

    ~optional()
    {
        if (ptr) {
            ptr->~T();
        }
    }

    optional& operator=(T obj)
    {
        if (ptr) {
            *ptr = std::move(obj);
        } else {
            ptr = new ((void*)&storage) T(std::move(obj));
        }
        return *this;
    }

    explicit operator bool()
    {
        return ptr != nullptr;
    }

    T& value()
    {
        if (!ptr) {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        return *ptr;
    }

    // Other const-correct and rvalue-correct accessors left
    // as an exercise to the reader
private:
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> storage;
    T* ptr;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cdf1a2090f33d04)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is literally impossible -- to default construct an object without a default constructor. 
Perhaps consider adding a `T nodeValue` parameter to `createNode()`? Or change the `Node` itself so that rather than holding an object, it holds a pointer to the object. That seems like a memory management nightmare, but it could work.

Comment: Well yes, I understand that I cannot construct classes without default constructors, but then what would be the correct approach to manage uninitialized values? As for your second point for the allocator, I am unsure what that means. Finally, creating a pointer _could_ work, but that would be a mess (As you said). I was actually looking for how the standard library does this; would you have any idea of how containers such as `std::list` handle their memory when they are initialized in a way such as `std::list<Test> test(9)` (How are the nodes initialized)?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah The `std::list` constructor that takes a count default-constructs all of the elements by default. Technically, it [default-insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultInsertable)s them, so they're constructed by calling the allocator's `construct` function.